# Why to create seperate reducer for react nativation while react-navigation redux setup?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

At present I am working on React Native and while setting up react-navigation and redux, I have seen many articles creating a seperate reducer like this.

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {
    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
};
```

and passing this reducer in the combineReducers and connecting as below.

```
@connect(state => ({
    nav: state.nav
}))
class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator
                navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                    state: this.props.nav
                })}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default function NCAP() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppWithNavigationState />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

But I am using the react navigation without creating any reducer as below

```
import { AppNavigator } from './router';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppNavigator/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the above two methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from doc -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux

Briefly: 
 - can use navigation not only from screen ( from `saga`/`redux`/`redux thunk` )